# Word.Selection содержит \a

Tags: c#, char, ms-word

Привет !

При работе с `word`, используя `Word.Selection` возвращается `'\r'`. 
Я раньше это удалял используя `.Trim()`.
Когда я работаю с **таблицами**, то `Word.Selection` возвращает `'\r\a'`. И `.Trim()` не удаляет `'\a'`.

Скажите пожалуйста, какую роль несет `'\a'` и почему это появляется именно при работе с **таблицами** ?

Спасибо !

Comment: Ну используется этот символ в качестве маркера окончания ячейки таблицы... почему - вопрос к M$... хотя какой ещё? все другие непечатаемые переносимые символы тупо заняты, а null - некошерно.

Comment: Просто у меня из-за этого, к названию объекта (который я записываю в ячейку) добавляется символ "name". Очень странно.
Но спасибо, теперь я уверен, что это Ворд так делает.

Comment: @Akina мне кажется, Ваш комментарий сойдет за ответ. Перенесите пожалуйста, я отмечу !

Comment: хорошо, перенесу...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну используется этот символ в качестве маркера окончания ячейки таблицы... почему - вопрос к M$... хотя какой ещё? все другие непечатаемые [переносимые символы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) тупо заняты, а null - некошерно.